# Retrieve keywords meta tag content with Simple HTML Dom?

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple HTML Dom to scrape keywords off remote web pages but I can't figure out quite how to achieve this.

I am currently using the following code.

```
$html = str_get_html($remote_html);
echo $html->find("meta[keywords]")->content;
```

And receiving the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Are you sure `$remote_html` contains keywords?

Comment: I am sure $remote_html contains keywords.

Comment: try `echo $html->find("meta[keywords]");`

Comment: Produces an empty array.

Answer (score 13):

find() returns not an object but an array containing (in this case) 1 object. Also 'keywords' is not an attribute, but 'name' is. Use:

```
$oHTML = str_get_html( $remote_html );
$arElements = $oHTML->find( "meta[name=keywords]" );
echo $arElements[0]->content;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$headers = array();
$headers["title"] = $html-> find("title",0)-> plaintext;
$headers["keywords"] = $html-> find("meta[name=keywords]",0) ->getAttribute('content');  
$headers["description"] = $html-> find("meta[name=description]",0) ->getAttribute('content');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$Inner_anchor = file_get_html("Your-Url");
$Inner_anchor->find("head meta[name='description']", 0)->content;
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
$html->find('meta[description]');
```

EDIT:

This might work better for your situation http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Comment: Still produces an empty array.

Comment: Hmm. not to sure. I dont really have much time to trouble shoot, but you might want to check out my edit above...

Comment: I more wanted to use the Simple HTML Dom library so I had more customization with the requests sent to fetch the remote page.